# Declare a constructor to correctly infer generic type from (keyof) argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I know that in TypeScript I can declare functions like these:

```
function doSomething<E extends Element>(el : E) : E;
function doSomething<N extends keyof ElementTagNameMap>(selector : N) : ElementTagNameMap[N];
function doSomething<E extends Element>(el : E | keyof ElementTagNameMap) {
  if(typeof el === 'string') {
    return document.createElement(el) as Element as E;
  } else {
    return el;
  }
}
```

Their usage will then be correctly typed

```
doSomething(document.querySelector('option')!) // return value typed as HTMLOptionElement
doSomething(new Image()); // return value typed as HTMLImageElement
doSomething('input'); // return value typed as HTMLInputElement
```

How can I achieve the same thing with constructors of generic classes?

```
class Some<E extends Element> {
  public element : E;

  constructor(el : E | keyof ElementTagNameMap) {
    if(typeof el === 'string') {
      this.element = document.createElement(el) as Element as E;
    } else {
      this.element = el;
    }
  }
}


new Some(document.querySelector('option')!); // Works, type is Some<HTMLOptionElement>
new Some(new Image()); // Works, type is Some<HTMLImageElement>
```

But I can’t seem to get the following to work:

```
new Some('input'); // Type is Some<Element> (the fallback) instead of Some<HTMLInputElement>
```

(Of course, using `new Some<HTMLInputElement>('input')` works but I should not have to explicitly type this if I already have the `ElementTagNameMap` doing this for me.)

I have tried adding overloads to the constructor, like I did to the function in the previous example:

```
constructor<N extends keyof ElementTagNameMap>(el : N) : Some<ElementTagNameMap[N]>;
// ⇒ Error: Type parameters cannot appear on a constructor function
constructor<N extends keyof ElementTagNameMap>(this : Some<ElementTagNameMap[N]>, el : N);
// ⇒ Error: A constructor cannot have a `this` parameter
```

I know I could create a helper function `createSome`:

```
function createSome<E extends Element>(el : E) : Some<E>;
function createSome<N extends keyof ElementTagNameMap>(selector : N) : Some<ElementTagNameMap[N]>;
function createSome<E extends Element>(el : E | keyof ElementTagNameMap) {
  return new Some(el);
}

createSome(document.querySelector('option')!); // Works: type is Some<HTMLOptionElement>
createSome(new Image()); // Works: type is Some<HTMLImageElement>
createSome('input'); // Works too now: type is Some<HTMLInputElement>
```

But isn’t there a way to achieve this directly? It seems counter-intuitive that I need to add a run-time construct (helper function) to get a specific compile-time behaviour (type inference).

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? Do I understand correctly, that you don't like the fact that the code: ```new Some(new Image());``` creates an instance of the ```Some<Element>``` type, instead of the ```new Some<HTMLImageElement>``` ?

Comment: @MarkDolbyrev yes. Or more specifically: how I can add an overload to the constructor that works the same way as the function example I gave.

Comment: @MarkDolbyrev I misread your comment: actually, `new Some(new Image())` types as intended, it’s `new Some('img')` that I want correctly inferred (via `keyof ElementTagNameMap`).

Comment: I updated my solution with something you might like even more; check it out.

Comment: @jcalz That’s amazing. I wish I could upvote again…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can't put a generic parameter on the `constructor` function because the type parameter for the constructor would [collide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10860#issuecomment-246456721) with any possible type parameter for the class itself:

```
new Some<WAT>('input'); // Is WAT the class param or the constructor param?
```

There are definitely places in TypeScript where the only way to get the compiler to understand what you're doing is to add runtime constructs ([user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) are an example of this).  So, your helper function `createSome()` is reasonable.  If you make the constructor private and include `createSome()` as a static method on the class, you've exposed only the behavior you want and it is still packaged fairly nicely:

```
class Some<E extends Element> {
  public element: E;

  private constructor(el: E | keyof ElementTagNameMap) {
    if (typeof el === 'string') {
      this.element = document.createElement(el) as Element as E;
    } else {
      this.element = el;
    }
  }

  static create<E extends Element>(el: E): Some<E>;
  static create<N extends keyof ElementTagNameMap>(selector: N): Some<ElementTagNameMap[N]>;
  static create<E extends Element>(el: E | keyof ElementTagNameMap) {
    return new Some(el);
  }
}
```

It isn't even that unwieldy for users:

```
// not so bad
Some.create(document.querySelector('option')!); // Some<HTMLOptionElement>
Some.create(new Image()); // Some<HTMLImageElement>
Some.create('input'); // Some<HTMLInputElement>
```

---

The only workaround I can think of that allows you to use a "generic constructor" without any runtime overhead would be to put the generic parameters in the class definition instead; and since there aren't any class "overload" definitions, you have to make a single signature that works for all cases.  Here's an example:

```
interface ElementTagNameMapWithDefault extends ElementTagNameMap {
  '***default***': Element;
}

class Some<E extends ElementTagNameMapWithDefault[N], N extends keyof ElementTagNameMapWithDefault = '***default***'> {
  public element: E;

  constructor(el: N);
  constructor(el: E);
  constructor(el: E | N) {
    if (typeof el === 'string') {
      this.element = document.createElement(el) as E;
    } else {
      this.element = el;
    }
  }
}
```

This works because the `Some<E,N>` class carries around both the `E` and the `N` type parameters, where the `N` parameter is only ever used in the constructor and then just gets dragged around later.  Since `N` has a default value you don't need to specify it (so you can just write `Some<E>`), and since the structural type of the class doesn't depend on `N` you can safely assign a `Some<E,N1>` to a `Some<E,N2>` and vice versa.

The new `ElementTagNameMapWithDefault` interface includes a made-up key `'***default***'` (you can probably use a [Symbol](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html) instead, but this is just a proof-of-concept) that allows the specified `E` type to include `Element`.  And since `N` defaults to `'***default***'`, the default value of `E` will be `Element`.

Let's make sure it works:

```
new Some(document.querySelector('option')!); // Some<HTMLOptionElement, "***default***">
new Some(new Image()); // Some<HTMLImageElement, "***default***">
new Some('input'); // Some<HTMLInputElement, "input">
```

All good.  Of course it allows this nonsense:

```
new Some('***default***'); // don't do this
```

which is why you'd probably want a private Symbol if you did this in practice.

But don't do this in practice; it's ugly and terrible.  The static `create()` method is probably the least messy solution in TypeScript.

---

If you really want generic constructors, you might head over to [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) and try to reopen [Microsoft/TypeScript#10860](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10860) or make a new issue that references it.  Perhaps a proposal about how to deal with distinguishing constructor type parameters from class parameters would be needed?  (`new<CtorParams> Class<ClassParams>` ?)

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

---

#### UPDATE

Oh, wow, I have a better solution for you.  First, rename your class to something else so you can use the real name later.  Here, I've changed `Some` to `_Some`:

```
class _Some<E extends Element> {
  public element: E;

  constructor(el: E | keyof ElementTagNameMap) {
    if (typeof el === 'string') {
      this.element = document.createElement(el) as Element as E;
    } else {
      this.element = el;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, define the `Some<E>` and `SomeConstructor` interfaces specifying the types exactly as you want.  Note how in this case the constructor can indeed be overloaded and generified:

```
interface Some<E extends Element> extends _Some<E> {

}

interface SomeConstructor {
  new <N extends keyof ElementTagNameMap>(el: N): Some<ElementTagNameMap[N]>
  new <E extends Element>(el: E): Some<E>
}
```

Finally, just declare that `_Some` is a `SomeConstructor` and give it the name `Some`:

```
const Some: SomeConstructor = _Some;
```

This is such a tiny amount of runtime overhead that I hope you find it acceptable (`var Some = _Some` at emit)

Now, watch it work:

```
new Some(document.querySelector('option')!); // Some<HTMLOptionElement>
new Some(new Image()); // Some<HTMLImageElement>
new Some('input'); // Some<HTMLInputElement>
```

What do you think of that?

Comment: user-defined type guards are a run-time feature because they assert something that can only be asserted at run-time, whereas the `ElementTagNameMap` is completely determined at compile time so I don’t think that’s an apt comparison…

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice, @jcalz. your answers are always detailed and explained very well.